# Fail to find C libs in /lib/libc

Tags: shared-library

I learned the C libs locate in

```
/lib/libc.so.6 or /lib64/libc.so.6, but this file
is sometimes a symbolic link to a file of another name, such as /lib/
libc-2.15.so.
```

However, I could find it

```
me@host:~$ ls /lib
apparmor       cpp       hdparm    klibc-wBFLvVtxy4xJqEadIBJMa78iJz8.so  modprobe.d  recovery-mode  udev
brltty         crda      ifupdown  linux-sound-base                      modules     systemd        ufw
console-setup  firmware  init      lsb                                   netplan     terminfo       x86_64-linux-gnu
me@host:~$ ls /lib64
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

How could I locate the C libs in ubuntu 18.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64 bit libraries are found in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  and the 32 bit libs are in /lib/i386-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1):

You could run

```
me@host:~$ whereis libc
```

to find the exact locations of both shared and static libc libraries

Comment: it's very amazing.